# Theme Hook Suggestion for Drupal 5

Tags: theming, 5

I wonder if any still remember how to override a particular node in Drupal 5 ? I have tried out several ways but didn't work. Couldn't find such info any more on google.

node-13.tpl.php

node--13.tpl.php

Comment: double dash is for D7, have you included the preprocessor function in template file https://www.drupal.org/node/249726

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 5 you need to add the suggestion yourself by placing this function in your theme's template.php:

```
function _phptemplate_variables($hook, $vars = array()) {
  switch ($hook) {
    case 'node':
      $vars['template_files'] = array('node-'. $vars['nid']);
      break;
  }
  return $vars;
}
```

Once that's done you'll be able to use node-13.tpl.php (note the single dash).

Source: [Separate node template for a specific node](https://www.drupal.org/node/136647).